# library used in java application (running on tomcat) doing read/write on files

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Java application that runs on tomcat and uses jersey to receive and answer REST requests, I now need to integrate a functionality by using a library that needs to read from a file and write on another file (as the library is built now, both files have to be provided via String representing their path). I know the best way to handle file r/w is not using the absolute path, but can it be done in practice?